# How can I get the current script name and line number in Rhino?

Tags: java, javascript, exception, applet, rhino

I am creating a game engine using Java and Mozilla Rhino, and I want all errors to call one function and provide it with the error message, like

```
...
} catch(Exception e) {
    Abort(e);
}
...
public void Abort(str) {
    System.out.println("Script error in "current_script_name+" line: "+line_number\n\n"+e);
}
```

This is easy for RhinoException, but I want to have the same thing for others, like IOException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit how the exceptions are being thrown, so I'll need to take a guess. And it depends on the optimization level you're using to execute Rhino.

I am guessing that exceptions are being thrown out of native Java code (i.e., you are not using `throw new Packages.java.io.IOException("...")`). In that case, you can use printStackTrace() to figure it out. Here's a little script (named `test.jsh.js`, which you will see in the stack trace) you can run in the Rhino shell:

```
try {
    //  foo does not exist
    var stream = new Packages.java.io.FileInputStream("foo");
} catch (e) {
    e.rhinoException.printStackTrace();
}
```

... and its output:

```
$ java -jar $(cygpath -w /opt/java/rhino/1.7R2/js.jar) -opt -1 test.jsh.js
org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.io.FileNotFoundException: foo (The system cannot find the file specified) (test.jsh.js#4)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1773)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.newInstance(MemberBox.java:202)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.constructSpecific(NativeJavaClass.java:281)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.construct(NativeJavaClass.java:200)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:3377)
        at script(test.jsh.js:4)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2487)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.evaluateScript(Main.java:564)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFileSecure(Main.java:486)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFile(Main.java:452)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processSource(Main.java:443)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.processFiles(Main.java:196)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main$IProxy.run(Main.java:117)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:515)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.exec(Main.java:179)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main.main(Main.java:157)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: foo (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.newInstance(MemberBox.java:194)
        ... 18 more
```

If you really want to use exactly the `Abort()` function you have above, you can parse the appropriate line out of the stack trace above; alternatively, you can display the whole stack trace, which may be more helpful, depending what you want to do.

Comment: I was kind of thinking of doing that but I wanted to know if there was an easier/more straightforward way. Thanks anywho

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you setup some kind of logging feature for your exceptions like Log4j? With this, you can set a `properties` file, that way every time you log something it outputs the same way (instead of always calling an `Abort()` function. Also, Log4j supports getting line numbers and other features: [Log4j Patterns.](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

Comment: I need to use an abort function because I'm reimplementing a game engine, and my goal is to have games that run in that game engine also run in this.